# Producer/Consumer pattern with a batched producer

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library, task

I'm attempting to implement a fairly simple Producer/Consumer style application with multiple producers and one consumer.

Research has led me onto the `BlockingCollection<T>` which is useful and allowed me to implement a long-running consumer task as below:

```
var c1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var buffer = new List<int>(BATCH_BUFFER_SIZE);

    foreach (var value in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        buffer.Add(value);
        if (buffer.Count == BATCH_BUFFER_SIZE)
        {
            ProcessItems(buffer);
            buffer.Clear();
        }
    }
});
```

The `ProcessItems` function submits the buffer to a database and it does work in batches. This solution is sub optimal however. In baron production periods it could be some time until the buffer is filled meaning the database is out of date.

A more ideal solution would be either to run the task on a 30 second timer or short circuit the `foreach` with a timeout.

I ran with the timer idea and came up with this:

```
syncTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerElapsed), blockingCollection, 5000, 5000);

private static void TimerElapsed(object state)
{
    var buffer = new List<int>();
    var collection = ((BlockingCollection<int>)state).GetConsumingEnumerable();

    foreach (var value in collection)
    {
        buffer.Add(value);
    }

    ProcessItems(buffer);
    buffer.Clear();
}
```

This has the clear problem that the `foreach` will be blocked until the end, defeating the purpose of the timer.

Can anyone offer a direction to take? I essentially need to snapshot the `BlockingCollection` periodically and process the contents the clear it. Perhaps a `BlockingCollection` is the wrong type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `GetConsumingEnumerable` in the timer callback, use one of these methods instead, adding the results into a list until it returns `false` or you've reached a satisfactory batch size.

[BlockingCollection.TryTake Method (T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - probably what you need, you don't want to perform further waiting at all.

[BlockingCollection.TryTake Method (T, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287154%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[BlockingCollection.TryTake Method (T, TimeSpan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287247%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can easily extract that out into an extension (untested):

```
public static IList<T> Flush<T>
(this BlockingCollection<T> collection, int maxSize = int.MaxValue)
{
     // Argument checking.

     T next;
     var result = new List<T>();

     while(result.Count < maxSize && collection.TryTake(out next))
     {
         result.Add(next);
     }

     return result;
}
```

Comment: I went with this implementation which works perfectly. It runs every x seconds and only pushes what is available (no waiting). Thanks for your help. https://gist.github.com/AntSwift/d2faa4f43d1a6d594172

Comment: A full working version is now available at https://github.com/AntSwift/AS.BlockingCollectionDemo

Comment: I believe that your code examples would be subject to race conditions due to the timer mechanism.  If your consumer can't complete the task within the timer period, the timer will fire regardless causing another consumer to be spawned.

Comment: @Andrew: That depends on the Timer implementation used, which is outside the scope of this answer, which is just about the blocking collection itself.